# Android Studio: How to 'Refresh' after adding file?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add a layout to an Android project:

Right clicked on `res` folder `New | Directory`. The directory was created however not shown under `app/res`. Maybe because empty dirs are hidden by default? Went to Windows explorer and added a file to the newly created directory (hidden in Android Studio). Back in the Studio, how can I 'refresh' the project structure to show the newly created directory and the file under it?

Essentially my question is, what is the alternative to Eclipse' Refresh menu option?

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Have you tried exploring your project via the different options (above your project you have the options for Android, Packages, and Project. One of the other views may give you what you want.

Comment: @zgc7009 Correct! The 'Structure' view is what I needed.

Answer (score 38):

If I find that Android Studio is out of synch with the file system I use `File->Synchronize`. Or equivalently, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> or the little circle with arrows menu button.

Comment: If this doesn't work you can try `File` > `Invalidate Caches and Restart` which will rebuild the project index

Comment: Also, if you find a way to avoid using the OS's file system and instead add files/directories from within Android Studio, you might reduce the likelihood of needing to do the rather time consuming `Invalidate Caches and Restart`

Comment: It looks as if this has been renamed 'Reload All From Disk'.

Answer (score 13):

In the case of device files - right click on the directory in question in the Device File Explorer and click on 'Synchronize'

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Comment: It looks as if this has been renamed 'Reload From Disk'.

Answer (score 5):

There is a view option right on top of the hierarchy folders (see attachment). Select "Packages"

[image: Screenshot of project menu in Android Studio]]

Answer (score 1):

**Mac**

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

**Windows**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

Comment: Note: this is just a shortcut to build

Comment: And linux is not an operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be, in Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 at least:

- 'File->Synchronize' refreshes project expolers Project view correctly
- BUT it doesn't refresh the Android view. 'File->Invalidate caches and restart' refreshed this view for me.
  View is selectable from the drop down list up in the project explorer frame.