# Android Studio Refresh Layout without Rebuilding Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot find how to refresh my project without rebuilding it in Android Studio. I have seen this popup near the logcat in the past and used it, it was wonderful for layout updates.

Is this refreshing just a layout change not available in Android Studio?

Comment: what does mean "refresh project"?

Comment: What I mean here is, restarting my activity without code changes, only layout changes...

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646639/android-studio-2-2-layout-editor-refresh-button which will also refresh updated drawable images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to: [Android Studio: How to 'Refresh' after adding file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374726/android-studio-how-to-refresh-after-adding-file)

There is no refresh option for do that on `AndroidStudio`

There is only an option for `Make project` in `Build -> Build Project`.

**But, i think this option will do the refresh option:**

`File->Synchronize`. Or equivalently, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> or the little circle with arrows menu button.

**Update:** In the new Android Studio, This feature is available. Thanks to jason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This isn't it... but great to know! It allowed me to restart my app, with XML changes, but not code changes.

Comment: Yw, but i think this is not possible or perhaps you are looking for something weird :)

Comment: This is possible with an update to the android studio version... I somehow had and older version running?!

Comment: @jasonflaherty I've updated the answer. Thank you for mentioning about it.

Comment: New features, You know :)

Comment: I have Android Studio 2.3.3 and get this error when when viewing a layout in design mode. Android studio says 'try and refresh layout' but there is no way to do that. Rebuilding does not take care of the error. Same message.

Comment: @BrianReinhold Updating to the last version will help maybe?

Answer (score 10):

Because the answer isn't stated anywhere in this thread even though it's marked as accepted:

Click on your preview and press `R`

Source: [How to refresh preview on Android Studio 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786229/how-to-refresh-preview-on-android-studio-2-2)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the question was about refreshing the layout without rebuilding the project, thanks man!

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in "Iguana". I'm looking for an alternative.