# android studio 2.2 layout editor refresh button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

can someone help me find the refresh layout button which was there before studio 2.2 to refresh the layout changes?

Have searched every where but cannot find it.The problem is sometimes drawables are not refreshed and reflected in the preview window.

Comment: there is no refresh button in stable version of android studio 2.2 for preview or for that you need to downgrade to 2.1.2 version.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think it is a small bug, but I find a hack solution to resolve the problem.

You can change a resource id to a wrong name. For example, you have a resource named `ic_launcher`. When you input `ic_launcher1`, you can find the interface like this:

[image: sample screenshot]

Next, click the refresh link (sometimes, it says 'clear cache').

I tried changing the orientation, but it does not work when I replace an existing image file.

Comment: @Subho I have replace an image and modify some words

Comment: actually this is what i found and have been using

Comment: Change orientation sometimes do not work. This worked for me, thanks. Why they removed this button? Pointless...

Comment: Worked for me. Cool.

Comment: Nothing worked for me. Sticking with closing the layout file and re-opening it :P

Comment: It's not a solution. It's a workaround. This is the right way of how to refresh layout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059284/2557258

Comment: I solve it by building app again. after a build UI back to normal.

Answer (score 36):

It's pretty simple to refresh.

Click on the preview screen, make sure that the preview window has the focus, and press <kbd>R</kbd>. It should display the progress in the top-right corner while refreshing.

If it doesn't work for any reason, switch to the design tab and press <kbd>R</kbd>. It refreshes the layout instantly.

Comment: Works just fine :) Thanks for the tip

Comment: I don't get why they remove the Refresh button. The Layout Editor is always buggy.

Comment: Be sure to select an element in the *Layout Editor* in case pressing `R`  doesn't refresh the layout.

Answer (score 19):

Toggle the Orientation button in Editor, it is refreshing the changes.

Comment: Doesn't update ImageViews if I change images in drawables directories. Android Studio 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Can't seem to find the refresh layout button too, it's as if it is deliberately removed.

However, I found a temporary refresh layout solution: On the screen orientation button, click the dropdown and then change the Night Mode. See this [page](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html) for reference on where to find the screen orientation button. Hope this helps.

Comment: night mode does nothing for me

Answer (score 0):

Close edited layout file and reopen.

You can do this with following shortcuts:

- `Ctrl+F4` (close tab)
- `Ctrl+Shift+E` (open Recently edited files)
- `Enter`
  (select recent file to open, your layout file should be already
  highlighted if edited last)