# layout refresh is not available in android studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

After updated to Android Studio 2.2, Refresh layout option not available. How to get this button?

[image: Layout Preview]

Comment: really good question..In our team all are waiting for answer

Comment: Yeah me too Ranjith

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio 2.2 layout editor refresh button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646639/android-studio-2-2-layout-editor-refresh-button)

Answer (score 1):

After lot of search google may remove the refresh button in **Android Studio 2.2**

refer this - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html

Incase your layout not get refreshed try the following solutions

Solution1 works for me when I use PercentRelativeLayout.. 
When first time my layout not refreshed.. after rebuild layout refreshed for me.

**Solution 1:**

Please rebuild your project **(goto Build -> Rebuild project)**

or

**Solution 2:**

**Note: This is not proper answer.. Its just trick**

Incase if your layout not get auto-refreshed try the following steps

just set the background to anyview 
for ex:

```
 android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

and then rename drawable name with wrong value.. and save again.. you will get error..

after remove this line your layout may refreshed..

[image]