# How to refresh a resource in Android Studio without restarting?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-drawable, android-layout-editor

I'm working on resizing and changing background images. However, each time I have to restart Android Studio so the Layout Preview will refresh the image.

**Doesn't work:**

- Changing API level
- Changing Preview orientation
- Changing theme
- Synchronizing project

What else can I do?

On Android Studio 2.2.2, Windows 10 64-bit on AMD A8-6410 with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics, 11 GB of RAM.

Comment: Have you tried this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646639/android-studio-2-2-layout-editor-refresh-button#39657645)?

Comment: @RavirajSubramanian It didn't work for me. But I just tried it and it did. Weird. Voting to close as duplicate

Comment: @RavirajSubramanian actually, this isn't a duplicate. That link's a different question.

Comment: I did not vote as duplicate, just trying to help you.

Comment: @RavirajSubramanian no, I said **I** voted as a duplicate but then I retracted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you're on pre-Android Studio 2.2:**  just hit the refresh button on the menu bar of the layout editor.

**Otherwise:**

Go to the layout you're working on. Then, change any resource to an incorrect name.

For example, if you have a button with this attribute:

```
android:background="@drawable/button"
```

Replace it with any random false resource:

```
android:background="@drawable/thisIsSomethingVeryRandomAndDoesntExist"
```

Then, you'll get something similar to this:

[image]

Click the "Refresh" *(Sometimes "Clear Cache")*, then go and undo the changes you did with the attribute. Voila!

Sometimes even changing the orientation works.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646639/android-studio-2-2-layout-editor-refresh-button#39657645)