# How to refresh preview on Android Studio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-layout, preview, android-studio-2.2, android-layout-editor

Now on **Android Studio 2.2** on new **Preview** mode, there are **no more refresh button**:

[image]

- Image 1: Preview on Android Studio 2.2 (without refresh button)
- Image 2: Preview on Android Studio 2.1 (with refresh button)

> Does anyone know how to display it again? Or with shortcut maybe?

**Edit:** If I change a drawable by example and that the change does not appear in the layout, the only method that works for me is closed and restart the project. If I close the layout and as I re-opens nothing happens. Same result using the "Synchronized" button.

Comment: i thought it was automatically refreshed when you changed something ?

Comment: @eriuzo This is the case for the xml but not for resources (drawable). In this case the refresh button of the preview discards the cache. This is essential.

Comment: What worked for me is changing between "design" and "text" tabs. In most of cases the layout was refreshed properly, but I had situations that I had to close layout and open once more. It is very sad that Google throw away this feature. Apparently new Android Studio (2.2.) is still not perfect.

Comment: @jakubbialkowski If I change a drawable by example and that the change does not appear in the layout, the only method that works for me is closed and restart the project. If I close the layout and as I re-opens nothing happens. Same result using the "Synchronized" button.

Comment: You can't, but there's some workaround. You can remove anything from an XML which will cause it to has an error, A refresh button saying you can try to refresh the view. Just click it
other than that, simply you can't.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Refresh feature is not removed, it is there; It's pretty simple to refresh:

Click on the preview screen to make sure preview window has the focus and press <kbd>R</kbd>. It should display the progress in the right-top corner while refreshing.

If it doesn't work for any reason,  switch to design tab and press <kbd>R</kbd>, it refreshes the layout instantly.

Comment: Thx, Confirmed it works. (even if I didn't notice the progress bar...)

Answer (score 22):

I think it is a small bug. But I find a hack solution to resolve the problem, you can modify the a resource id to a wrong name, for example, you have a resource named 'ic_launcher', when you input 'ic_launcher1', you can find the interface like that:

[image]

next step, click refresh icon(sometimes it is 'clear cache' label). it is works for me.

I have try to change the orientation, but it not works when I replace a exist image file.

May your problem is same as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646639/android-studio-2-2-layout-editor-refresh-button

Comment: And i mentioned it brother @ MarsPeople

Answer (score 10):

> Display again?

I guess you cant. Apparently the refresh functionality has been removed because they think the processing will happen much faster and will auto-refresh the previews real time. The Layout Editor's document has no mention of refresh functionality.

> Shortcut?

If you are faster in making changes to your layout than Android-studio refreshes, you could try toggling between the `design` and `blueprint` views using the shortcut <kbd>B</kbd>

Refer the [Layout Editor Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html) for other shortcuts you might feel comfortable with or works for you.

Comment: Of all the buttons  Google could have removed they chose the Refresh button!? What is this nonsense >.<

Answer (score 5):

So do the Simple Step. When you change your layout then save it and clean your project.
 `go to menu Build -> Clean Project.`

I Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no refresh button in stable version of android studio 2.2 for preview. But there is a work around to do so. **By toggling the orientation button in an editor will refreshes the changes!**

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same Problem , sometimes changing the Android Version worked
and it'll sure work if you clean/Rebuild the project

Answer (score 1):

The new Android Studio Electric Eeel 2022.1.1 has this refresh option

[image: Here]

Answer (score 0):

Find the double diagonal lines below your preview layout and click them. It will refresh your layout.

[image: Double Diagonal Line]