# How to refresh XML in Android Studio when replacing a picture?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, when I overwrite a picture, how to refresh the XML (the one who references the picture) to show the new one?

I tried many ways to change it. Only reboot the Android Studio can do it!

Can someone tell how to do it?

Comment: link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786229/how-to-refresh-preview-on-android-studio-2-2